# Questions about catching Unix signals

Tags: unix, signals

The following code catches the "SIGINT" signal only once and then interrupts (program exists):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void IntHandler(int value);

void CatchIntSignal()
{
    struct sigaction intAction;
    intAction.sa_handler = IntHandler;
    sigemptyset(&intAction.sa_mask);
    intAction.sa_flags = 0;
    //if to uncomment any of "0" or "SIG_IGN" - IntHandler will be never called:
    //intAction.sa_sigaction = 0/*SIG_IGN*/;
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &intAction, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("sigaction() failed.\n");
    }
}

void IntHandler(int value)
{
    printf("IntHandler(%d)\n", value);
    //uncommenting this does not help:
    //CatchIntSignal();
}

int main()
{
    CatchIntSignal();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How must I modify this code to preserve program's exit after SIGINT catching?
If to set **intAction.sa_sigaction** to 0 or to SIG_IGN - IntHandler will never be called - but why? Which undefined value does it have to say system that "it's necessary to call IntHandler"? If I will set some handler to **intAction.sa_sigaction** - this handler will be called (but IntHandler will not). How does system know that I did set something to **intAction.sa_sigaction**?

Comment: I do not understand what you want your program to do.  Is it: the first time SIGINT is received, IntHandler is called, and then the program exits?  Or is it: Every time SIGINT is received, IntHandler is called; the program does not exit until getchar() returns?

Comment: I want so that my program will catch SIGINT signals and will not exit after it. So that after each "Ctrl+C" program will print "IntHandler(2)" and keep working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `sa_handler` and `sa_sigaction` fields of `struct sigaction` are actually *the same field*.  Quoting the (OSX) manpage for `sigaction(2)`:

```
 struct  sigaction {
         union __sigaction_u __sigaction_u;  /* signal handler */
         sigset_t sa_mask;               /* signal mask to apply */
         int     sa_flags;               /* see signal options below */
 };

 union __sigaction_u {
         void    (*__sa_handler)(int);
         void    (*__sa_sigaction)(int, struct __siginfo *,
                        void *);
 };

 #define sa_handler      __sigaction_u.__sa_handler
 #define sa_sigaction    __sigaction_u.__sa_sigaction
```

So your assignment to `sa_sigaction` is overwriting the handler you already set. You should just set `sa_handler` and leave `sa_sigaction` alone. This is how `CatchIntSignal` should read:

```
void CatchIntSignal()
{
    struct sigaction intAction;
    intAction.sa_handler = IntHandler;
    sigemptyset(&intAction.sa_mask);
    intAction.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &intAction, NULL) != 0)
        printf("sigaction() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

(You may need to add #includes of `string.h` and `errno.h` to get the `strerror(errno)` bit to compile.  Always include `strerror(errno)` in error messages triggered when system calls fail.)

(CORRECTION: added `SA_RESTART` to flags per ninjalj.)

Comment: Union... you revealed the truth for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is probably that the system call is interrupted, so the `getchar()` returns, probably with EOF.  And the next thing the program does is exit...

So, you could try checking what `getchar()` returns, reset the error status on `stdin`, and call `getchar()` again to get the next signal.

Comment: So the OP should either set `SA_RESTART` on `sa_flags` or check for `EINTR` on `getchar()` failure.

Comment: Aieee! I should have remembered `SA_RESTART`.  Thanks for pointing that out ninjalj.

Comment: @Zack, @ninjali - I too should have remembered SA_RESTART.

Answer (score 0):

After you have caught the interrupt signal and handled in your catch codes, you need to set the handling back to `SIG_DFL`.

EDIT: Ignore please. This is applicable only to the old unix signal().

Comment: Not with `sigaction()`; that is a primary benefit of `sigaction()` over `signal()`.  If `signal()` was used, you would be more nearly correct.  The handler would be reset to SIG_DFL automatically, and it would be necessary to reset the handler in the handler.